# NextJS baseUrl configuration not working on Github Actions

Tags: reactjs, next.js, github-actions

I am using Github Actions to run CI and CD for my NextJS app (v9.4.4).

I currently have a `jsconfig.json` file as the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

This is great as I can do `import Nav from "components/Nav"` in lieu of `import Nav from "src/components/Nav"` and is working perfectly locally (with either `next dev` or `next build`).

However, when I try to build the NextJS app on Github Actions, it errors with:

```
./src/App/index.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'contexts/firebase' in '/home/runner/work/MyFirebaseApp/MyFirebaseApp/src/App'
```

For context, a sample of my file structure is:

```
MyFirebaseApp
│   .github
│   next.config.js
│   jsconfig.json
│   ...more config files...  
│
└───src
│   │
│   └───App
│   │   │   index.jsx
│   │
│   └───components
│       │   Nav.jsx
│   │
│   └───contexts
│       │   firebase.jsx
```

I have tried changing the baseUrl to `home/runner/work/MyFirebaseApp/MyFirebaseApp/src` without any luck.

Is there special webpack configuration or changes I need to make for this to build on Github Actions?

Comment: Did you find any ans to this? I am facing same issue for Create-React-App